# c# several background workers same method

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

i have the problem, that something is going wrong when 2-8 backgroundworkers accessing the same method.
so here is an example:

```
int threadnumber = 0;
int retries[] = new int[8];

private XmlDocument GetXML(string ApiUrl, int threadnumber)
        {
            var mySourceDoc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
                httpRequest.Timeout = 50000;
                if (cb_Proxy.Checked == true)
                {
                    WebProxy germanserver = new WebProxy();
                    Uri newUri = new Uri("http://" + txt_Proxy.Text);
                    germanserver.Address = newUri;
                    httpRequest.Proxy = germanserver;
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                receiveStream.ReadTimeout = 150000;
                mySourceDoc.Load(receiveStream);
                receiveStream.Close();
                retries[threadnumber-1] = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //DialogResult MessBox = MessageBox.Show("Der Server ist nicht erreichbar oder es ist ein anderes Problem mit dem Server aufgetreten. Es wird automatisch 3 mal erneut versucht. Fehlermeldung anzeigen?", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                //if (MessBox == DialogResult.Yes) MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                retries[threadnumber - 1]++;
                consoletext = "Fehler: " + ex.Message + "; Neuer Versuch " + retries[threadnumber - 1] + " von Url " + ApiUrl + Environment.NewLine;
                if (threadnumber == 1) workingHelper1.ReportProgress(counterhelper[0]);
                if (threadnumber == 2) workingHelper2.ReportProgress(counterhelper[1]);
                if (threadnumber == 3) workingHelper3.ReportProgress(counterhelper[2]);
                if (threadnumber == 4) workingHelper4.ReportProgress(counterhelper[3]);
                if (threadnumber == 5) workingHelper5.ReportProgress(counterhelper[4]);
                if (threadnumber == 6) workingHelper6.ReportProgress(counterhelper[5]);
                if (threadnumber == 7) workingHelper7.ReportProgress(counterhelper[6]);
                if (threadnumber == 8) workingHelper8.ReportProgress(counterhelper[7]);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (retries[threadnumber - 1] > 1 && retries[threadnumber - 1] <= 3) GetXML(ApiUrl, threadnumber);
                if (retries[threadnumber - 1] >= 4) retries[threadnumber] = 1;
            }
            return mySourceDoc;
}
```

The backgroundworkers calling the method getxml with generated url strings and the threadnumber 1-8.
My problem is, that sometimes the retries reaches 5 or higher. so i think that backgroundworkers accessing sometimes the same variable and count it up?

Comment: Is there any reason to use background workers instead of TPL or similar?

Comment: this is a good question. i have never think about another options as backgroundworkers. is it right, that when several backgroundworkers accessing same method the variable e.g. threadnumber can be overridden in runtime by another worker?

Comment: it's very likely, the recursive calls between threads do not help too much to understand what can be happening there. You could make your method `async` and `await` for its result from other method, then retry the call as many times as you need.

Comment: In your `>= 4` case, shouldn't that be `retries[threadnumber - 1]`? Otherwise that's going to crash with thread number 8.

Comment: How about ditching the `retries` array and adding another parameter? `GetXML(string ApiUrl, int threadnumber, int retries)`. The first time you call, pass 0 for the last parameter, and when you do a recursive call, pass `retries+1`. Or, pass 5 (or whatever your max retries is) as the initial parameter, and do the recursive calls with `retries-1`. When you get to 0, you can return failure status. In general, though, your recursive solution is kind of convoluted. Also, you're not properly disposing of things when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to allow multiple threads to manipulate the same object at the same time. This is definitely going to cause conflicts in the state of the manipulated objects.

Consider using a `lock` on the lines where your shared variables (i.e. `threadnumber` and `retries`) are accessed and manipulated.

Consider also the way that you're calling the method because:

1. It seems like that each worker thread requires 2 entries from the `retries` array (i.e. `threadnumber` and `threadnumber - 1`) So, you cannot be calling the `GetXML` method with consecutive `threadnumber` values or else you will get conflicts in the `retries` array. Or perhaps this is a bug (quoted below) in your code that is causing this problem.

   > if (retries[threadnumber - 1] >= 4) retries[threadnumber] = 1;
2. Consider the code that is calling the `GetXML` method and make sure it doesn't assign the same `threadnumber` to multiple workers.

Comment: `threadnumber` is a parameter rather than a shared variable. And, whereas `retries` is accessed concurrently, it's always indexed with `threadnumber-1` (except in one case, which I mentioned in comments), so it's not likely that shared variable access is the problem.

Comment: but i think the problem is threadnumber...e.g. getxml(bla1, 1) and then at same time next worker getxml(bla2, 2) and so i think in method the threadnumber can be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it was an logical failure. now i have debugged each thread an the actual variables content. so there it seems all ok and no variable can be overridden.

and so i have edited the code, so that after the third retry the method aborts.

```
private XmlDocument GetXML(string ApiUrl, int threadnumber)
    {
        object thislock = new object();
        lock (thislock)
        {
            var mySourceDoc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
                httpRequest.Timeout = 50000;
                if (cb_Proxy.Checked == true)
                {
                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
                    Uri newUri = new Uri("http://" + txt_Proxy.Text);
                    proxy.Address = newUri;
                    httpRequest.Proxy = proxy;
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                receiveStream.ReadTimeout = 150000;
                mySourceDoc.Load(receiveStream);
                receiveStream.Close();
                retries[threadnumber - 1] = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retries[threadnumber - 1]++;
                if (retries[threadnumber - 1] == 4)
                {
                    consoletext = "Endgültiger Abbruch von Url " + ApiUrl + Environment.NewLine;
                    writeLog("Worker: " + threadnumber + " Endgültiger Abbruch von Url " + ApiUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    consoletext = "Fehler: " + ex.Message + "; Neuer Versuch " + retries[threadnumber - 1] + " von Url " + ApiUrl + Environment.NewLine;
                    writeLog(ex.Message + "; Versuch: " + retries[threadnumber - 1] + " Thread: " + threadnumber + " URL: " + ApiUrl);
                }
                //DialogResult MessBox = MessageBox.Show("Der Server ist nicht erreichbar oder es ist ein anderes Problem mit dem Server aufgetreten. Es wird automatisch 3 mal erneut versucht. Fehlermeldung anzeigen?", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                //if (MessBox == DialogResult.Yes) MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                if (threadnumber == 1) workingHelper1.ReportProgress(counterhelper[0]);
                if (threadnumber == 2) workingHelper2.ReportProgress(counterhelper[1]);
                if (threadnumber == 3) workingHelper3.ReportProgress(counterhelper[2]);
                if (threadnumber == 4) workingHelper4.ReportProgress(counterhelper[3]);
                if (threadnumber == 5) workingHelper5.ReportProgress(counterhelper[4]);
                if (threadnumber == 6) workingHelper6.ReportProgress(counterhelper[5]);
                if (threadnumber == 7) workingHelper7.ReportProgress(counterhelper[6]);
                if (threadnumber == 8) workingHelper8.ReportProgress(counterhelper[7]);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (retries[threadnumber - 1] > 1 && retries[threadnumber - 1] <= 3) GetXML(ApiUrl, threadnumber);
                //if (retries[threadnumber - 1] >= 4) retries[threadnumber - 1] = 1;
                else retries[threadnumber - 1] = 1;
            }
            return mySourceDoc;
        }
    }
```